# White spaces in sed search string

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I want to substitute a String from a file which is:

```
#     - "server1"
```

My first attempt was something like this:

```
sed -i 's/#\     -\ "\server1"\.*/ChangedWord/g' file
```

But I get an error if I try it like this.

So there is to be another way to handle whitespaces, I guess I have to use \s or [[:space:]]. But for some how I am not able to make it work.

Comment: what error do you get? show some sample input file and desired output to make it more clear. Also, if you are using `sed -i` in a file from `/root` you better create a backup with `-i.bak`

Comment: It says: sed: invalid option -- ' '

Comment: Are you using OSX? There, `sed -i` needs an argument, can be just `sed -i ''`.

Comment: No I'm running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Why do you have backslashes in the expression? Try removing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are complicating the expression too much. This should be enough:

```
sed 's/^#[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*"server1".*/ChangedWord/' file
```

It looks for those lines starting with `#` followed by 0 to n spaces, then `"server1"` and then anything. In such case, it replaces the line with `ChangedWord`.

Note I am using `[[:space:]]` to match the spaces, since it is a more compatible way (thanks Tom Fenech in comments).

Note also there is no need to use `g` in the `sed` expression, because the pattern can occur just once per line.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
#     - "server1"
hello#     - "server1"
$ sed 's/^#[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*"server1".*/ChangedWord/' a
hello
ChangedWord
hello#     - "server1"
```

Comment: This works if I am on the machine but it is not if I want to ssh the command like `ssh -i file user@IP sed 's/^#\s*-\s*"server1".*$/ChangedWord/' file`

Comment: `.*` is greedy, so no need to anchor to the end of the line `$`.

Comment: Also `\s` is only gonna work with some versions of sed - better to use `[[:space:]]`, or just ` ` if it's just normal spaces.

Comment: @Brave does it work if you remove the `$` as described by Tom? `ssh -i file user@IP sed 's/^#\s*-\s*"server1".*/ChangedWord/' file` Probably the `$` gets expanded.

Comment: @fedorqui no, I deleted the $ still not working. But I already executed the following which is working properly with ssh: `ssh -i file user@IP sed -i 's/#\ storm.zookeeper.servers.*/storm.zookeeper.servers:/g' file` So that it should work in general....

Comment: @Brave then give a try with `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s` as [again] Tom suggested. Or just spaces.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks for your support. But it is still not running through ssh. On a local machine all these expressions are working perfectly. Maybe I will need to find another solution then...

Comment: @Brave define "it is not working" and show what is the output. I cannot blindly suggest changes : )

Comment: @fedorqui I posted my solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The actual fault was the missing escaping from the double quotes:

```
 ssh -i file root@IP sed 's/^#[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*\"server1\".*/ChangedWord/' file
```

That did it for me. Thanks for all your support

Comment: It is weird, since the `sed` command was using single quotes. Good finding!

Answer (score 0):

[rghome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161917/white-spaces-in-sed-search-string/31162864#comment50332566_31161917) is right, you don't need those backslashes in front of spaces as the expression is wrapped in quotes. In fact, they're causing the error: `sed` is telling you that `\<Space>` is not a valid option. Just remove them and it should work as expected:

```
sed -i 's/#     - "server1"/ChangedWord/' file
```

Comment: You are right it works well if I execute it as a local command. When I try to ssh it to execute it on a remote machine it is not substituting anything...

Comment: Ah, I see. Your question didn't mention anything about executing over SSH though